# using python expect to run openvpn

Tags: python, expect, openvpn

i need a python script to run open vpn automaticaly
but i use sudo for run the open vpn

```
sudo openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config openvpn.conf &
```

thats my terminal command.  i have to give the password for sudo, can i use pexpect to run that command?
and i have to get the exit code because i want to know that the openvpn is run succesful or not

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can change /etc/sudoers so that openvpn command can be run without giving the password.

```
yourusername ALL=(all) NOPASSWD: /path/to/openvpn
```

and in python, do something like:

```
import subprocess
exitcode = subprocess.call(["sudo","openvpn","--cd /etc/openvpn --config openvpn.conf"])
```